# does using enter many times increase the size of the code?

Tags: angular, typescript, memory, prettier

I'm working on a project in **Angular 4** and **TypeScript**. Recently I've seen a video on VSCODE can do that. I installed `prettier` plugin for that. And ran that to make code look good and readable. I've done the same thing on script file too (i.e on TS file). What it did is it made it readable but the number of lines of code increased a lot.

lets assume I wrote an input

```
let input = {"root": {"firstname":input.firstname , "lastname": input.lastname , "mobilenumber": input.mobile}};
```

After I ran `prettier` the input which was a single line of TS code became like this.

```
let input = {

"root":{

"firstname":input.firstname ,

"lastname": input.lastname ,

"mobilenumber": input.mobile,

}

};
```

So it takes 6 to 7 lines of code.

#### Does this increase the file size as it is coming in a new line which is kind of like 'ENTER'?

I'm asking this because after this I got some memory error while giving build. And will it increase my page memory size too because almost all pages are around 40 to 50 MB when I checked it using chrome dev tools by taking heap snapshots.

[image: 40 - 50 mb page size]

Comment: Additional newlines and spaces/indentation will increase the file size of the source file by a tiny, tiny amount (compared to no spaces at all when not necessary), but it definitely won't have an effect on the memory usage of the script.

Comment: It would increase the file size in so much as there being an extra character per line, so you're looking at an extra x bytes per file where x is the number of character returns.

Does your code work when on a single line?

Comment: For production you can always Minify and Bundle code. So to keep the file size small.

Comment: @Prawns No need. It works in any way.

Comment: Just having your code well formatted will never cause "out of memory errors", the error must be somewhere else. I would find it a very bad excuse if someone told me: "I wrote this algorithm in one line to prevent memory errors".

Comment: @SehaxX thats obvious. When I give run the command ng build --prod. It minifies and uglifies.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I solved the memory errors. I was wondering if this could be a cause too. The memory error was just because I was calling up DOM elements many times.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks!! I understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces, it will increase the file size

Answer (score 0):

The size of your pacakaged code will depend on your build.

The main process behind the size of your page here will be the minification.
Quoting Wikipedia:

> Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing its functionality.

On development build, your code is usually not minified, so your page size will be greater.
But on production build, all your code should be minified and it will have no impact.